# How do i populate a dropdown menu from MySQL database in Flask using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a dropdown that gets its values from a MySQL database, here's the database code in the main.py file

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
DB_NAME = "base.db"

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='mysql+pymysql://root:pass123@localhost/base'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
```

here is the model

```
class Vehicle(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    reg = db.Column(db.String(45), unique=True, nullable=False)
    brand = db.Column(db.String(45), nullable=False)
    color = db.Column(db.String(45))
```

also below is the code in the html file

```
 <div class="dropdown" name= vehicle method="GET" action="/" align="center">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" >Vehicles
                <span class="caret"></span></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
                    {% for row in vehicle %}
                        <li>
                            <option value="{{row[0]}}">{{row[1]}}</option>
                        </li>    
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </div>
```

and here's the route (which i suspect is the source of the problem)

```
@app.route('/')
def main():
    cur = MySQL(db).connect.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Vehicle ORDER BY id")
    vehicle = cur.fetchall()
    return render_template('/', vehicle = vehicle)
```

the dropdown button appears fine on the web page but when i click it a small empty space appears which makes me think that the problem is from the route file and the `vehicle = cur.fetchall()` is empty even though i have added values in the database

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: the last paragraph is literally the question, i just had to provide all the rest for context

Comment: well after investigating the code you share I can conclude that the problem is apparently found when executing the *cursor*, you could share the model that your database uses, maybe you are not using the correct statement `"SELECT * FROM Vehicle ORDER BY id"`

Comment: i added the table class but i don't think it's the source of the problem

Comment: your db may be empty because you haven't inserted data in it, I really can't determine why this is caused, but if your problem persists I would recommend you to rebuild everything again guiding you with some documentation or tutorial from a different [library](https://flask-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: i actually have a CRUD page in the web application that lets the admin add update and delete "vehicles" to the database, so i'm pretty sure the database is full since i can literally see what i add.. i'll try rebuilding and see if the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

db is SQLAlchemy object,
try using

```
vehicle = db.session.execute("SELECT * ...").fetchall()
```

Comment: i'm sorry i don't understand, i replaced what's inside `app.main` with what you suggested but it's still not working...

Comment: in main.py after app is create, initialise extension db.init_app(app) if you are using flask-sqlalchemy